# Approvals showing "Created by: [my email address]" instead of the user who is submitting the request

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, flow, approval-process, approval

I am working on a Flow for a SharePoint list when a request for PTO is submitted, it will start an approval process.

I wanted to see if I can change the section of the email from the Approval that says "Created by:" as it has my email (I am assuming it is because I created this section in the flow) but I would want it to say the name of the employee requesting PTO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot change the creator information in approval email.

As per the Microsoft official documentation for [known limitations of approvals](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/approvals/#known-issues-and-limitations),

> The creator of the flow will ***always*** be shown in the Approval details (email content and all clients). This is to prevent spoofing of approval sender identities.

---

If you want to show the name of user who submitted the request, you can do that in **Requestor** field in approval action.

For Example:

[image]

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. I suppose I will create a new account for approvals to be 'created by' I just did not want my email address attached to them every time an approval starts. Thanks!